# Form appears different between Blend and VS2010

Tags: wpf, blend

When the attached form is viewed in Blend 4, it appears as it should during both design and run time.  When viewed in VS2010, it appears very different in the design window.  However, it appears correct when running.  Any clues?
This is the code:

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    x:Class="LibraWPF.frmLoadTips"
    x:Name="Window_MainLoadTips"
    Title="Load Tips" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" WindowStyle="None" ResizeMode="NoResize" Background="{x:Null}" Visibility="Visible" AllowsTransparency="True" Height="164" Width="305" IsEnabled="True" SizeToContent="Manual" MinWidth="305" MinHeight="164">

    <Border Margin="0,0,8,8" d:LayoutOverrides="HorizontalAlignment" BorderThickness="1,0,1,1" >
        <Border.BorderBrush>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource HeaderBkgd}"/>
        </Border.BorderBrush>
        <Border.Effect>
            <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="8" ShadowDepth="2" Color="#FF707070" RenderingBias="Quality"/>
        </Border.Effect>

        <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" >
            <Grid.Background>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource LibraContainerBkgd}"/>
            </Grid.Background>
            <Label Content="Load Tips" Height="27.333" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontFamily="Segoe UI Symbol" FontSize="14.667"  >
                <Label.Background>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource HeaderBkgd}"/>
                </Label.Background>
            </Label>
            <Label Content="Select Tip Load Position:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="27.491" Margin="37.684,41.427,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="154.473" FontWeight="Bold"/>
            <ComboBox Margin="220.002,41.427,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="36" IsEditable="True"/>
            <Button Content="Go" Margin="37.684,91.173,0,0" x:Name="btnLoadTipsGo" Height="53.672" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="100.437" />
            <Button Content="Cancel" Margin="160.739,91.173,0,0" IsCancel="True" IsDefault="True" Click="btnLoadTipsCancel_Click" x:Name="btnLoadTipsCancel" Height="53.672" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="100.437" />
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 1):

The VS 2010 xaml editor does a poor job resolving design-time resources. I usually have both Studio an Blend open at the same time when working in SilverLight or WPF.

Comment: I assumed as much, but this is fairly bad.  In VS, more than half the height of the two buttons are cutoff by the lower edge of the window.  If I adjust it in VS to look correct, then it gets thrown off in Blend and in runtime.